# How to add local database file to Visual Studio Mac 2017

Tags: c#, database, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm creating a hotel management service in C# on Visual Studio (Mac) and I can't seem to find a good explanation on how to add a local database file to my project. I created my database table in open office (.odb file) but there doesn't seem to be a way for me to implement this in my project. The documentation has nothing on this either. Any one got a clue how to add databases to a Mac Visual studio project?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

there are no localDB in visual studio for mac, you need to install the docker image for sql server.

[here is the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-docker)

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know that. But after docker is installed and I have the sql server how would I put that into the project? I can't find any button that allows me to connect a database anywhere, do you know?

Comment: @Jumpman987 after you have the docker sql server you just need to change your appsettings.json and change your connection string.

Comment: Can you please let me know what would be the connection string parameters we need to specify if connect to docker?

Comment: @user2695433 something like : "Data Source=ServerName; Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;User id=UserName; password=yourpassword;" where the Data Source will be the ip of your docker container. happy coding.

Comment: @Abiezer , when I checked the Ip through Kinematic it shows localhost:<port> , Is that the one I have to use?

Comment: @user2695433 yes, it is

Answer (score 3):

You can run SQL Server on a Mac now:

https://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-a-mac/

Using Docker it can be made as your localhost SQL Server. I've done this and it works. SQL Management studio for Mac is useful too.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

### Consider using sqlite instead

---

Microsoft RazorPagesMovie tutorial using **sqlite** instead of **localdb** in Visual Studio 2019 for Mac:

1. Follow [Tutorial: Get started with Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio-mac)
2. And the second part: [Add a model to a Razor Pages app in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio-mac)