# c# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Snix_Connect in macOS

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, macos, entity-framework

I am writing an asp.net 5 app with ef 7 to work with sql server. It's all okay when the app is running under windows. When I tried running it under macOS and when i need to interact with the database the following exception appeared:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
>   Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 25 - SNI_ERROR_25)
>   Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 25 - SNI_ERROR_25) --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The socket is not
>   connected   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SSRP.GetPortByInstanceName
>   (System.String browserHostName, System.String instanceName) [0x00049]
>   in :0    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.CreateTcpHandle
>   (System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.DataSource details, System.Int64
>   timerExpire, System.Object callbackObject, System.Boolean parallel)
>   [0x00047] in :0    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor
>   (System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   System.Object providerInfo, System.Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SessionData reconnectSessionData, System.Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling) [0x00156] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions options,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, System.Object
>   poolGroupProviderInfo, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool pool,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningConnection,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions) [0x0012a] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection
>   (System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool pool,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions options,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions) [0x0000c] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) [0x00184]
>   in :0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) [0x00040]
>   in :0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject, System.UInt32
>   waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, System.Boolean allowCreate,
>   System.Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal& connection) [0x000a4]
>   in :0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal& connection) [0x00026]
>   in <fd07d03de70b4f52944f513cf6c7845e>:0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningConnection,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal oldConnection,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal& connection) [0x0021d]
>   in :0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection outerConnection,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions) [0x00036] in
>   <fd07d03de70b4f52944f513cf6c7845e>:0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection outerConnection,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry)
>   [0x0005d] in <fd07d03de70b4f52944f513cf6c7845e>:0    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open () [0x0003b] in
>   <fd07d03de70b4f52944f513cf6c7845e>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection t,
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionInterceptionContext
>   c) [0x00000] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1[TInterceptor].Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext]
>   (TTarget target, System.Action`2[T1,T2] operation,
>   TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, System.Action`3[T1,T2,T3]
>   executing, System.Action`3[T1,T2,T3] executed) [0x0000f] in
>   <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection,
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext) [0x00042] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices+<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32
>   () [0x00099] in <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy+<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0
>   () [0x00000] in <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult]
>   (System.Func`1[TResult] operation) [0x00036] in
>   <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute
>   (System.Action operation) [0x00020] in
>   <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection sqlConnection, System.Action`1[T]
>   act) [0x00050] in <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection sqlConnection, System.Action`1[T]
>   act) [0x0009f] in <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript
>   (System.Nullable`1[T] commandTimeout, System.Data.Common.DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, System.String createDatabaseScript) [0x0001b] in
>   <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection, System.Nullable`1[T]
>   commandTimeout,
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection) [0x00044] in <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection, System.Nullable`1[T]
>   commandTimeout,
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection) [0x00018] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase ()
>   [0x00030] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection) [0x0001e] in
>   <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists
>   (System.Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) [0x00036] in
>   <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists
>   (System.Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) [0x00000] in
>   <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update (System.String
>   targetMigration) [0x00014] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update ()
>   [0x00000] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase
>   (System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext internalContext,
>   System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] createMigrator,
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext objectContext) [0x0002d]
>   in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase
>   (System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext objectContext,
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
>   [0x00012] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create
>   (System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
>   [0x00095] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1[TContext].InitializeDatabase
>   (TContext context) [0x00063] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext+<>c__DisplayClassf`1[TContext].b__e
>   () [0x00011] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction
>   (System.Action action) [0x00016] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization
>   () [0x000a5] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b__4
>   (System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext c) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1[TInput].PerformAction
>   (TInput input) [0x00038] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction
>   (System.Action`1[T] action) [0x00057] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize () [0x0000b] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType
>   (System.Type entityType) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[TEntity].Initialize ()
>   [0x0000e] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[TEntity].get_InternalContext
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[TEntity].ActOnSet
>   (System.Action action, System.Data.Entity.EntityState newState,
>   System.Object entity, System.String methodName) [0x0002a] in
>   <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[TEntity].Add
>   (System.Object entity) [0x00014] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[TEntity].Add (TEntity entity) [0x00017] in
>   <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at BibConsole.Program.Main
>   (System.String[] args) [0x00037] in
>   <2efdd2ce9e994658b659758521caa1ef>:0 
>   ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 [ERROR] FATAL
>   UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
>   Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 25 - SNI_ERROR_25)
>   Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 25 - SNI_ERROR_25) --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The socket is not
>   connected   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SSRP.GetPortByInstanceName
>   (System.String browserHostName, System.String instanceName) [0x00049]
>   in <fd07d03de70b4f52944f513cf6c7845e>:0    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.CreateTcpHandle
>   (System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.DataSource details, System.Int64
>   timerExpire, System.Object callbackObject, System.Boolean parallel)
>   [0x00047] in <fd07d03de70b4f52944f513cf6c7845e>:0    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor
>   (System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   System.Object providerInfo, System.Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions,
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SessionData reconnectSessionData, System.Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling) [0x00156] in
>   <fd07d03de70b4f52944f513cf6c7845e>:0    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions options,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, System.Object
>   poolGroupProviderInfo, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool pool,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningConnection,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions) [0x0012a] in
>   <fd07d03de70b4f52944f513cf6c7845e>:0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection
>   (System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool pool,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions options,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions) [0x0000c] in
>   <fd07d03de70b4f52944f513cf6c7845e>:0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) [0x00184]
>   in <fd07d03de70b4f52944f513cf6c7845e>:0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) [0x00040]
>   in <fd07d03de70b4f52944f513cf6c7845e>:0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject, System.UInt32
>   waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, System.Boolean allowCreate,
>   System.Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal& connection) [0x000a4]
>   in <fd07d03de70b4f52944f513cf6c7845e>:0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningObject,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal& connection) [0x00026]
>   in :0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection owningConnection,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal oldConnection,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal& connection) [0x0021d]
>   in <fd07d03de70b4f52944f513cf6c7845e>:0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection outerConnection,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions) [0x00036] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection outerConnection,
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry,
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions userOptions) [0x00000] in
>   <fd07d03de70b4f52944f513cf6c7845e>:0    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] retry)
>   [0x0005d] in :0    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open () [0x0003b] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__36
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection t,
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionInterceptionContext
>   c) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1[TInterceptor].Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext]
>   (TTarget target, System.Action`2[T1,T2] operation,
>   TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, System.Action`3[T1,T2,T3]
>   executing, System.Action`3[T1,T2,T3] executed) [0x0000f] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection,
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterceptionContext
>   interceptionContext) [0x00042] in :0
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices+<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32
>   () [0x00099] in <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy+<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0
>   () [0x00000] in <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult]
>   (System.Func`1[TResult] operation) [0x00036] in
>   <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute
>   (System.Action operation) [0x00020] in
>   <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection sqlConnection, System.Action`1[T]
>   act) [0x00050] in <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection sqlConnection, System.Action`1[T]
>   act) [0x0009f] in <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript
>   (System.Nullable`1[T] commandTimeout, System.Data.Common.DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, System.String createDatabaseScript) [0x0001b] in
>   <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection, System.Nullable`1[T]
>   commandTimeout,
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection) [0x00044] in <5c51bb66ce2c412d8224b39ad2626fbe>:0
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection, System.Nullable`1[T]
>   commandTimeout,
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection) [0x00018] in :0
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase ()
>   [0x00030] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection connection) [0x0001e] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists
>   (System.Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) [0x00036] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists
>   (System.Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update (System.String
>   targetMigration) [0x00014] in :0
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase
>   (System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext internalContext,
>   System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] createMigrator,
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext objectContext) [0x0002d]
>   in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase
>   (System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext objectContext,
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
>   [0x00012] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create
>   (System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
>   [0x00095] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1[TContext].InitializeDatabase
>   (TContext context) [0x00063] in :0
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext+<>c__DisplayClassf`1[TContext].<CreateInitializationAction>b__e
>   () [0x00011] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction
>   (System.Action action) [0x00016] in
>   <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization
>   () [0x000a5] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4
>   (System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext c) [0x00000] in
>   <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1[TInput].PerformAction
>   (TInput input) [0x00038] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction
>   (System.Action`1[T] action) [0x00057] in
>   <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase ()
>   [0x00000] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize () [0x0000b] in
>   <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType
>   (System.Type entityType) [0x00000] in
>   <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[TEntity].Initialize ()
>   [0x0000e] in :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[TEntity].get_InternalContext
>   () [0x00000] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[TEntity].ActOnSet
>   (System.Action action, System.Data.Entity.EntityState newState,
>   System.Object entity, System.String methodName) [0x0002a] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[TEntity].Add
>   (System.Object entity) [0x00014] in
>   <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[TEntity].Add (TEntity entity) [0x00017] in
>   :0    at BibConsole.Program.Main
>   (System.String[] args) [0x00037] in
>   <2efdd2ce9e994658b659758521caa1ef>:0 
>   ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Comment: SNI_ERROR_25=Connection string is not valid. Maybe your connection string containes Integrated Security true?

Comment: no it does not contains any integrated security

Comment: Any update on this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

what i found is that there are no localDB in visual studio for mac.
take a look at this

> [How to add local database file to Visual Studio Mac 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866441/how-to-add-local-database-file-to-visual-studio-mac-2017)