# Having problem with opening a SQL connection in Xamarin by c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin.forms

I'm having a problem with opening a SQL connection. I'm using C# and I don't know what is wrong with that code. The program reads the connectionstring and SQLconnection commands, but cannot execute connection.Open(), it breaks the program. Can anybody help me?

This will be used in a Xamarin app. I tried with two backslashes \, also with one \, but still didn't work?

The error I get is, Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 25 - SNI_ERROR_25)

Is the problem related to the "Integrated Security=True" definition?

```
SqlCommand command;
SqlConnection connection;

if (Regex.IsMatch(player, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$"))
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-DG5B04G\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=denemeGame;Integrated Security=True";
    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    connection.Open();
    command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Winners (PlayerName, PlayerScore) VALUES (@PlayerName, @PlayerScore)", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerName", player);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerScore", finalScore);
    connection.Close();
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

I copy the code below to a windows form and checked out does it work or not. And it works. There should be a hint in Xamarin Forms, can anyone knows anything about sql connections in Xamarin!!!!!

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(player, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$"))
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-DG5B04G\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=denemeGame;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Winners (PlayerName, PlayerScore) VALUES (@PlayerName, @PlayerScore)", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerName", player);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlayerScore", finalScore);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
    else
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: You're using a verbatim string (`@"..."`), so you only need one backslash.

Comment: @madreflection backslash to where?! Like that?
@"Data Source=DESKTOP-DG5B04G\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=denemeGame;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: In your connection string...  `@"Data Source=DESKTOP-DG5B04G\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=denemeGame;Integrated Security=True"` <-- only need one backslash in the Data Source value because of the `@` prefix.

Comment: Also, you're not executing the command, and you should dispose both SqlConnectim and SqlCommand, and don't use AddWithValue.

Comment: @madreflection nope it didn't work. I tied every variation with and without @, with \\, with \, but no. Program throws this message: Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 25 - SNI_ERROR_25)'

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the complete message. It'll get lost in the comments.

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52465409/c-sharp-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-snix-connect-in-macos#comment91872617_52465409). It suggests that Integrated Security is not supported on Xamarin. Try using SQL Authentication.

Comment: What error do you get? What does "Cannot open" mean? Can you access the DB with SSMS?

Comment: connecting directly to a server DB from a mobile app is a horrible security risk and should be avoided at all costs

Comment: you are also assuming your mobile device can find DESKTOP-DG5B04G, that your firewall is open to any port needed by SQL, that SQLExpress can handle remote connections, etc...

Comment: @Jason This database is not gonna open to the public! I just wanna see that the code I wrote works or not! When you are working on a project you wanna see everything works, right!

Comment: ok, then all of the points in my 2nd comment are worth considering

Comment: basically that error is "cannot connect to server" error, regardless of that, listen to others, step back and take a different approach, (server side app for example)

Comment: Integrated security means that you try to connect as the current user to that db. I doubt that those credentials can be transferred between mobile and desktop

Comment: OT that regex allowes a player name of only spaces